# Bulk Generating URL aliases for taxonomy terms doesn't do anything

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

In D7, I've imported ~8000 taxonomy terms. All these need to have a url alias, based off their names.

I can check the 'Generate automatic URL alias' checkbox when editing each taxonomy term individually but I cannot go through and do this for all 8000.

I tried updating the paths with Bulk Generate. In the Patterns tab for my taxonomy term vocab I have set `[term:name]`. But when I hit Bulk Generate it doesn't update anything.

Would anyone know of a solution? An SQL query perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to troubleshoot your own site configuration to understand what's not causing the path update on the bulk form. If you look at the flow of execution, you can follow

- [The bulk update submission handler](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/pathauto/tree/pathauto.admin.inc?h=7.x-1.x#n290)
- [The bulk update batch processor](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/pathauto/tree/pathauto.pathauto.inc?h=7.x-1.x#n55)
- [The bulk updater](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/pathauto/tree/pathauto.module?h=7.x-1.x#n936)

Ultimately, all the form is doing to update is using [`pathauto_taxonomy_term_update_alias_multiple()`](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/pathauto/tree/pathauto.module?h=7.x-1.x#n936) to load/save a group of tids in bite-sized chunks; if you fail to pinpoint the problem, you can use that function to do what you're already doing manually.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the SQL:

```
UPDATE pathauto_state SET pathauto="1" WHERE entity_type="taxonomy_term";
```